# Keep high score through app updates

Tags: android, libgdx, preferences

My app uses LibGdx, and it saves high scores using Preferences.  However, I want to make an update to the app, but don't want all the users who downloaded it to lose their high scores.  Will the high score get erased with an update?  And is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: SharedPreferences persist through update.

Comment: Is there a difference between SharedPreferences and Preferences, or are they the same thing?

Comment: Preferences is the default SharedPreference file. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: @henzdaddy Take a look into the wiki about the shared preferences: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences:

> On Android, the system's SharedPreferences class is used. This means
>   **preferences will survive app updates**, but are deleted when the app is
>   uninstalled.